# cURL issues with HTTPS and Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, ssl, curl, https

I'm trying to connect to Facebook's graph api using the PHP-SDK.  The session is being created fine, however I'm getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 1: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl thrown in .../app/vendors/facebook/graph/facebook.php on line 622
```

I have tried to correct this by adding the following lines to facebook.php at line 600

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
```

to disable the SSL checking, but I am still getting the same error.  How can I fix this issue so that I can interact with the FB api? Do I need to recompile cURL or should I add a certificate for FB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your version of PHP hasn't been compiled with SSL support. (Always verify the peer certificate and the host name when using HTTPS, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have the following two lines under the Curl section of phpinfo()

Comment: cURL support  enabled
cURL Information  libcurl/7.19.5 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

Comment: What about OpenSSL support? (Google for PHP, libcurl and OpenSSL)

Comment: also 'Configure Command' contains '--with-openssl' does that mean that ssl is supported?

Comment: Does the *curl* section in `phpinfo` have an *SSL Version* row? Do you have an *OpenSSL* section in `phpinfo`?

Comment: There is an OpenSSL section which reads enabled and "OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008", however Curl information reads "    libcurl/7.19.5 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 ".  Does that mean I need to recompile PHP or just install the PHP-Curl bindings (sorry, I'm completely new to all this, normally just a coder)

Comment: Yes, it sounds like libcurl didn't have ssl enabled. You might need to recompile or install it from another package (it depends on your environment/platform).

Comment: I recompiled curl and php to enable SSL and now it's working fine, thanks for the help