# facebook autorization S_REQUEST["code"] returns nothing and SSL error 107

Tags: php, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

**I use  this code below.**

```
     $app_id = my_app_id;      
     $app_secret = my_app_secret;

     $canvas_page = my_canvas_page;



     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream";


     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");   


     $code = $_REQUEST["code"];


     $file = "help.txt";
     $fh = fopen($file, "w+") or die("File ($file) does not exist!");

     fwrite($fh,  $code); 
 fclose($fh);
```

**$_REQUEST["code"]  return empty and i have error 107 ( net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR). But real url contain code value**

(https://plazma-tambov.ru/advanced/fb/?code=AQB_w2iFHofA8rzlr9FGD0EmA_BtWVhMmAJgsWo-YTgakgJ-YXibkd1_634pYZZL8UDds9ZlRHtKiWunGz5-2oWfKsrxpaur75t2PFPY9INuqCAL5kBtJsS_Bt9Vf-2WvHkDBtLYgzhUSk3InuV8IU3V6dwu9upGvH6ETDMLBY124JJBM3VMO6EF0eCjZg4ZsNU#*=*)

**If     i add next code**

```
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $token_url . "'</script>");
```

the real url contain empty for code variable

(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fplazma-tambov.ru%2Fadvanced%2Ffb%2F&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&code=)

**Why S_REQUEST["code"] returns nothing ?**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it often helps to add

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
```

in the "makeRequest" method in base_facebook.php. Also you should make sure that $_SERVER is NOT damaged by some script. It won't work if the data in $_SERVER is escaped in a wrong way.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958594/curl-issues-with-https-and-facebook-graph-api).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not use facebook.php and base_facebook.php.